# Onclick with submit button not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to put onlick for submit button. I googled 
many tutorial sites implement all the hints but all that can't solve the problem. When i put an alert inside the called function the alert is working 
but the tasks which is inside of page-join.php not work. When i put 
onclick with an image that's work pretty well. What the problem please  guide, Due to the form submtion i am not getting the problem in firebug 
console. So i didn't get what the real problem is.

```
//This is my function that i am calling from onclick.

  function deltpopdtl()
   {
  var ipss = '<?php echo $baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/includes/';

  $.ajax({
  url: ipss+"page-join.php?delpopdtl=<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>",
  success: function(data){
     }
  });}


// This is my php code(page-join.php)
     if(isset($_GET['delpopdtl'])) 
                {
       global $db;
       $getdetail = "DELETE  FROM firstloadpop WHERE rsc_id=".$_GET['delpopdtl']." and user_id= $user_id";

            mysql_query($getdetail);
             }
//This is my form and submit button
<form method="post" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#"> 

<input type="submit" id="abc" name="onladinvite" value="sendinvitation" onclick="return deltpopdtl();" />
 //i put only onlick deltpopdtl(); but the same situation, i also tired
 //onclick="return deltpopdtl();return false" but all vain

</form>
```

Comment: when debugging, `console/network` tab is your friend

Comment: If the form doesn't actually do anything, why not just use a `<button>`?

Comment: Your code work fine check this link http://jsfiddle.net/6hhq09z2/1/

Comment: The form is doing another works as well. Actually the form send invitation to the friends and i want that if the submit button clicked and the invitation sent then delete some records from another table.

Comment: As ajax is been implemented either stop the form submission or change the input type to `type="button"`

Comment: To my knowledge this looks contradictory. Because once you click on the button, the form gets submitted and the ajax call I guess will never happen or happen and stop in the middle due to refresh

Comment: remove onclick in submit and add <form method="post" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" onsubmit="return deltpopdtl();">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. You have to write `return false` before function end because your form is submitted and you cant see your ajax effect.
> 2. You can change your `submit` button to `type='button'`

```
function deltpopdtl()
{
  var ipss = '<?php echo $baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/includes/';    
  $.ajax({
         url: ipss+"page-join.php?delpopdtl=<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>",
         success: function(data){}
  });
  return false;  //You have to add this line because your form is submitted and you cant see your ajax effec
}
```

Comment: But the form is also doing some task to insert the data into database when  we put button  instead of the submit  thats stops working?

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this

```
function deltpopdtl()
   {
  var ipss = '<?php echo $baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/includes/';

  $.ajax({
  url: ipss+"page-join.php?delpopdtl=<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>",
  success: function(data){
     }
  });

   return false;
}
```

you can add **return false** at the end of function body so it do not submit  form and also you can debug with firebug

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you submit the form the code execute and while doing so it's interrupted and the page reloads. To prevent that you can use the `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default nature of a submit button.

```
function deltpopdtl(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var ipss = '<?php echo $baseUrl ;?>/themes/gr-mist/includes/';

  $.ajax({
     url: ipss+"page-join.php?delpopdtl=<?php echo $_GET['pageid'];?>",
     success: function(data){
     }
  });
}

//your html button
<input type="submit" id="abc" name="onladinvite" value="sendinvitation" onclick="deltpopdtl(event);" />
```

Comment: The form is doing another works as well. Actually the form send invitation to the friends and i want that if the submit button clicked and the invitation sent then delete some records from another table. i implement this its works well for the delete but when the invitation to friends part stopped working.

Comment: @OpenSource, You want to check if the invitations were sent?
If so, then send the invitations via ajax and then in the `success` function do another ajax function which will delete the records you wanted.